# How to prove this integration value is one ????

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, harmonic-functions

For $0 \leq r<1$ and $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$ how to prove that the integral value is one.
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(\theta) d \theta=1
$$

The function here defined by the function
$$
P_r(\theta)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} r^{|n|} e^{i n \theta}
$$

Comment: I know this function is a 2\pi periodic function, and converges absolutely and uniformly.

Answer (score 2):

Since the series converges uniformly, we can interchange the series and the integral to get that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(\theta)~\mathrm{d}\theta=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{r^{\lvert n\rvert}}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{in\theta}~\mathrm{d}\theta.$$

Now recall that

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{in\theta}~\mathrm{d}\theta=\begin{cases}
2\pi,&n=0,\\
0,&n\neq 0,
\end{cases}$$

and so the above reduces down to

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(\theta)~\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{r^{\lvert 0\rvert}}{2\pi}2\pi=1.$$